# how can I make a table from auto from ACF function

Tags: r

I run the function `acf()` and get some lags value of my variable which is `ret_excess`, the problem is that I want these values to be represented into a nice table, how can I do it.

```
acf(average_monthly_return$ret_excess,plot=FALSE,na.action=na.fail)
```

the output is this:

[image]

So I want those values to be in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot access your data, I will use `BJsales` data as an example on how to make a table from ACF data.

1. Create an object to store the `acf` result, which is a list.

```
dat <- acf(BJsales, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.fail)
```

2. Extract only two elements, namely the lag and the acf values, from the object, and store them in a data.frame object.

```
acf_df <- data.frame(lag = dat$lag[,,1], acf =  dat$acf[,,1])
acf_df
#   lag       acf
#1    0 1.0000000
#2    1 0.9832837
#3    2 0.9647593
#4    3 0.9447464
#5    4 0.9226258
```

3. To create a relatively nice table from the, use `kable` and `kable_styling`.

```
library(kableExtra)
acf_df |> kable() |> kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "stripped", 
                                   full_width = FALSE)
```

Part of the resulted table:

[image]

**Edit**

In case you want to make the lags as the columns, you can use `pivot_wider`. For example:

```
library(tidyr)
acf_df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "lag",
              names_prefix = "lag_", 
              values_from = "acf") |> 
  kable() |> 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered", "striped"))
```

The result:

[image]

As discussed in the comments, in case rownames are needed, the `tibble` resulted from `pivot_wider` above should be changed to `data.frame` first, and then the rows are named.
The following code can be used:

```
out <- acf_df |> 
       pivot_wider( names_from = "lag", names_prefix ="lag_",  
       values_from = "acf" ) |> 
       as.data.frame() 
rownames(out) <- "acf"  # because here acf_data has only one row.
out |> kable() |>
       kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered", "striped"))
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242907/discussion-on-answer-by-abdur-rohman-how-can-i-make-a-table-from-auto-from-acf-f).